# How to find url of attachment of a message collected by the await messages function in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to collect an image with the awaitMessages function but I can't seem to be able to get an image URL as I would normally get from a normal message.

Normally I am able to get the URL from a message by `message.attachments.toJSON()[0]["url"]` but now that doesn't work.

When I convert the collected messages to JSON by using `collectedMessages.toJSON()` it looks like this:

```
[
  {
    channelID: '809335881680289832',
    deleted: false,
    id: '840910718911905802',
    type: 'DEFAULT',
    system: false,
    content: '',
    authorID: '539789850983923712',
    pinned: false,
    tts: false,
    nonce: null,
    embeds: [],
    attachments: [ '840910718810456084' ],
    createdTimestamp: 1620559138754,
    editedTimestamp: 0,
    webhookID: null,
    activity: null,
    flags: 0,
    reference: null,
    guildID: '809079026224201800',
    cleanContent: ''
  }
]
```

and when i directly log the collected messages it looks like this:

```
Collection [Map] {
  '840912580015947837' => Message {
    channel: TextChannel {
      type: 'text',
      deleted: false,
      id: '809335881680289832',
      name: 'premium-verification',
      rawPosition: 1,
      parentID: '809079026224201801',
      permissionOverwrites: [Collection [Map]],
      topic: null,
      lastMessageID: '840912580015947837',
      rateLimitPerUser: 0,
      lastPinTimestamp: null,
      guild: [Guild],
      messages: [MessageManager],
      nsfw: false,
      _typing: Map {}
    },
    deleted: false,
    id: '840912580015947837',
    type: 'DEFAULT',
    system: false,
    content: '',
    author: User {
      id: '539789850983923712',
      system: null,
      locale: null,
      flags: [UserFlags],
      username: 'Mr.Astatine',
      bot: false,
      discriminator: '2270',
      avatar: 'f5cec89cb417760e0ff6aa82fb03fddf',
      lastMessageID: '840912580015947837',
      lastMessageChannelID: '809335881680289832'
    },
    pinned: false,
    tts: false,
    nonce: null,
    embeds: [],
    attachments: Collection [Map] { '840912579949625354' => [MessageAttachment] },
    createdTimestamp: 1620559582476,
    editedTimestamp: 0,
    reactions: ReactionManager {
      cacheType: [class Collection extends Collection],
      cache: Collection [Map] {},
      message: [Circular]
    },
    mentions: MessageMentions {
      everyone: false,
      users: Collection [Map] {},
      roles: Collection [Map] {},
      _members: Collection [Map] {},
      _channels: null,
      crosspostedChannels: Collection [Map] {}
    },
    webhookID: null,
    application: null,
    activity: null,
    _edits: [],
    flags: MessageFlags { bitfield: 0 },
    reference: null
  }
}
```

Please help me in getting the URL of the attachment from these types of collected messages.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `collectedMessages.first().attachments.first().url`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=first
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageAttachment?scrollTo=url

Comment: this didn't work for me i literally go no response when i console logged it

Comment: @RijakSingh did you just copy paste `message.attachments ...` or do you adapt it to your code (`collectedMessages.first().attachments.first().url`) ?